# SCSS ancestor sensitive selector

Tags: css, sass

This seems like something that must be doable somehow but I just can't find the answer anywhere.

Is it possible using SCSS to specify an element's style variant based on it being within a certain ancestor?

Example:

What I want in CSS:

```css
.parent1 .element,
.parent2 .element {
    /* style for .element in both parents */
}
.parent1 .element {
    /* special style for .element only when in parent1 */
}
```

What I would like to do in SCSS:

```
.parent1,
.parent2 {
    .element {
        /* style for .element in both parents */

        [SOME SCSS MAGIC] {
            /* special style for .element only when in parent1 */        
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise the nearest place I can put this style is outside of the entire `.parent1, parent2` block of code which is way to far to be convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice against it*... but you can use nth on selector lists - like:

*makes style less readable

**SCSS**

```
.parent1,
.parent2 {
    .element {
        /* all items in selector list */

        @at-root #{nth(&, 1)} {
          /* first item in selector list */
        }
        @at-root #{nth(&, 2)} {
          /* second item in selector list */
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.parent1 .element,
.parent2 .element {
  /* all items in selector list */
}

.parent1 .element {
  /* first item in selector list */
}

.parent2 .element {
  /* second item in selector list */
}
```

**Update**

To make it a bit more readable you could create a helper mixin à la:

```
@mixin selector-contains($substring) {
    @each $part in & {
        @if str-index($part+'', $substring) { 
            @at-root #{$part}{ @content; } 
        }  
    }
}

.parent1,
.parent2 {
    .element {
        @include selector-contains('.parent1'){
            /* first item in selector list */
        }
        @include selector-contains('.parent2'){
            /* second item in selector list */
        }
        @include selector-contains('.parent'){
            /* all elements */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use  **@at-root body .parent1 .element**

```
  .parent1,
    .parent2 {
        .element {
            /* style for .element in both parents */
              background: yellow;
              color: green;
            @at-root body .parent1 .element {
              color: red;
                /* special style for .element only when in parent1 */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this has been already suggested and so far this seems like the only solution. Not ideal though because of repeating code.

Answer (score -1):

```
.parent1,
.parent2 {
    .element {
        /* common styles */
    }
}

.parent1 .element {
    /* parent 1 element overrides */
}
```

which compiles to:

```
.parent1 .element,
.parent2 .element {
  /* common styles */
}

.parent1 .element {
  /* parent 1 element overrides */
}
```

### Edit

Or use a mixin to house common styles

```
@mixin commonStyles {
  /* Common to both parent1 & parent 2 */
}

.parent1 {
  .element {
    @include commonStyles;
  }
}

.parent2 {
    .element {
    @include commonStyles;

    /* parent 2 specific styles */
  }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.parent1 .element {
  /* Common to both parent1 & parent 2 */
}

.parent2 .element {
  /* Common to both parent1 & parent 2 */
  /* parent 2 specific styles */
}
```

### Edit 2

If you are motivated by keeping the two sets of styles together then just use two mixins.

```
@mixin baseStyles {
  /* Common to both parent1 & parent 2 */
}

@mixin modifiedStyles {
  /* parent 2 specific styles */
}

.parent1,
.parent2 {
  .element {
    @include baseStyles;
  }
}

.parent2 {
    .element {
      @include modifiedStyles;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, @MattFryer is correct. The problem is that the parent's style is really long and the styling for `.element` would thus be divided with 100 lines in between. That seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: define a mixin up the top with styles that are common to both. Then make overrides in `.parent2 .element`. See edits.

Comment: This is no different than defining styles for both separately, @IanPollak is asking if there is a way to define styles for both, then be more specific, within the same block. Sadly, I don't think it's possible, would save a lot of scrolling : )

Comment: It is different because the styles in question are only defined once.

Comment: This can be achieved using his current structure and putting the specific styles after

Comment: It sure can. And without sass!

Comment: The point is that he wants to keep the relevant styles together.

Comment: I won't discuss further, but it doesn't because the relevant styles are now in the mixin (separate and outside of the block). The issue is maintainability, grouping styles as closely together as possible is beneficial.

Comment: Interesting question / discussion though : )

Comment: I like the mixin in that now I have a line that basically says "look above for the rest of this element's styles". But otherwise it has the same drawbacks. The code is divided and I have to repeat and maintain the same ancestor structure (`.parentX .element`), which can be much more complex than this in two places.